# Viewing the profile page - what is seen is different depending on user id. Session issue

Tags: php, session, profile

I have a site that I'm working on building. I have a login/registration system in place and a member profile system in place.

When a user logs in, they are automatically directed to their profile page. They have the option to click an edit profile link and edit their data. They can also click another link to go back to viewing their profile.

Currently this works great.

The issue I am having is that I have a link in the navigation bar called 'User List'. This link should fetch a list of all the current users in the database, which it does with uid=(appropriate user id #) at the end of the url, however, when you click on any of these links, the profile it returns is for that of the logged in user, and not that for the name that they clicked.

I am aware that the issue is caused by my function in the profile.php page which states:

```
<?php 

include('core/init.inc.php'); 

$user_info = fetch_user_info($_SESSION['uid']);

?>
```

Since the profile page is being told to use the session uid, I understand that any redirect to the profile.php page will show the logged in users info.

So, if I change this function to $_GET['uid']' then my problems flip. I am able to correctly view the profiles for the users in the user list but then my logged in user can no longer view their profile or edit it since there is no call to the session uid.

So, I guess I'm wondering how I fix this. How do you separate profiles that are not for the logged in person vs their own individual profile? Please let me know what code you need to see and I'd be happy to post it.

Comment: Thanks for responding - do you have an example? I would need it to understand that if there is a uid=(random#) at the end of the url that it should pull that user id info and not the session info.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a check, If the `$_GET['uid']` is set then fetch user info using this variable otherwise use the session variable to fetch the user info.

```
<?php 

include('core/init.inc.php');    
if (isset($_GET['uid']) && $_GET['uid'] !='')
{
   $user_info = fetch_user_info($_GET['uid']);
}
else
{
   $user_info = fetch_user_info($_SESSION['uid']);
}    
?>
```

Comment: OMG you saved my life! That worked perfectly!! Thank you SO much. Literally spent like 3 days trying to figure this out. I'm SUPER new to PhP. Thank you!!!

Comment: OK I am messing around with this and it did solve the issue with the user list - I can now view those while logged into a session. Except now that I've logged in with a different user ID I realize that it's just showing me the profile information for user id #1 as my session info by default, regardless of which user ID I log in with, and I did clear my cache.

Comment: A var dump shows that it's pulling the correct info for the user, but what is displaying is different than the var dump.